# Right model approach for repeated observations

Tags: multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, repeated-measures, panel-data, nested-data

The problem:

- Panel Data, nested data or repeated observations for the same individual over eleven years. All independent variables are fixed effects and could be categorical or continuous variables. I have around 10,000 observations (individuals) in each and every one of those 11 years and 10 potential explanatory variables.
- The dependent variable is a continuous proportion (percentage) taking values between 0 and 1.
- This observational study aims to analyze the impact that changes in economic incentives have on the independent variable controlling for the rest of the variables. The economic incentives increase like a step function. They are measured in dollars and have the same value for all individuals over a few years, then the value increases and have the same value over a few years and so on.

What is the right model to use?

- For dealing with the target dependent variable, I am using a Beta distribution or Binomial using a logic link.
- For dealing with the dependence due to the repeated observations, there are several approaches like robust standard errors, GEE, fixed-effects or random-effects. What's the best approach here. I am using right now a Generalized Mixed Linear model with a random effect for the intercept but, any of my explanatory variables are random. So, probably is a wrong approach.

Comment: Well, given your huge sample size I am surprised you can even fit a mixed model (my first choice) and not have it crash at the start. Anyway, in the beginning you mention that the independent variables are fixed, then you go on to say that any of your explanatory variables are random?

Comment: Yes, I am saying that any of my explanatory variables are random effects in the sense that they don't have levels that are random selection from a much larger set of levels. Each and every explanatory variable exhaust  “the levels of a factor”.

Comment: Of course, because I have repeated measurements for subjects, I specified the subject ID variable as a grouping variable, which will fit random intercepts in the mixed model framework. So, I am not totally sure if I really need random factors among my explanatory variables.

Comment: In that case your independent variables are fixed effects and the only random effects are the individual ID's. Can you describe what these IV's are?